# How to make write conditional in Aerospike using Java client

Tags: java, caching, transactions, aerospike

How to write conditionally to an aerospike bin? I want to subtract value from aerospike bin and for that case I can use Operation.add(-1) then how to make it happen in a single transaction by first checking the value and if value is greater than zero then subtract 1 from the bin's value.
Please suggest with java client.

Answer (score 3):

Use Expressions in Java. Client source code is open. You can check many examples in the Test code and adapt. https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/8a4daba81bb5ab8496523be18e898a2d0ec8aec3/test/src/com/aerospike/test/sync/basic/TestExpOperation.java
Java API documentation is here: https://docs.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/

You will build an expression like so:

```
// a > 0
 Exp.gt(Exp.intBin("a"), Exp.val(0))
```

If Exp evaluates to true, implement the subtract operation.

Also note, if the only operation is the increment then a filter-expression shown above will work fine. If you are sending the increment along with other operations then they could use a write-expression (introduced in Aerospike 5.6.0).
The write expressions would be something like:

```
Exp.cond(
  Exp.gt(Exp.intBin("a"), Exp.val(0)), Exp.sub(Exp.intBin("a"), 1),
  Exp.unknown())
```

Using this method also assumes you would also want the other operations to execute if this operation fails so you would need to use the EVAL_NO_FAIL policy.